# Program Beckhoff PLC in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, twincat, st

Since Beckhoffs TwinCAT3 Shell is missing basic function that are considered standard in other IDEs im trying to switch to VS Code to do the job.

There is an extension that enables syntax highlighting for ST (Structured Text) which is great.
But im not satisfied how the TcPOU files (xml formatted) are displayed.

I'm used to the window layout of TwinCAT3 and am wondering if it is somehow possible to have a similar layout with VS Code.

In Beckhoffs TwinCAT3 Shell, which is based on Visual Studio, the decleration of variables and the code are seperated by a horizontal bar. Furthermore the header of the xml file is not displayed in TwinCAT3.

So basically what im asking is if i can make VS Code display

```
    <Declaration><![CDATA[

         ]]></Declaration>
```

as a horizontal line and hide the xml header.

[VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAtk0.png) [Beckhoff TwinCAT3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQDYE.png)

Comment: What "basic functions" are you missing? I've tried to go down this rabbit hole myself, and I ended wasting lots of time. Remember that the code-part is just a tiny fraction of TwinCAT 3 software development. You also have all the other system-manager related stuff, I/O, Safety etc that is tightly integrated into the TcXaeShell/"VS-Classic". Also remember that the PLC code is referenced by the project, so any addition/deletion of a POU/DUT will have to be reflected into the structure of the project.

Comment: For example automatic highlighting for all variables in the text when you select it.

Comment: Automatic highlighting of all variable instances will be introduced in TwinCAT 3.1.4026, when they finally release it.