# TwinCat TcXaeShell Text Editor - Text Highlight

Tags: visual-studio, text-editor

Many IDE text editor have a feature to highlight the text when a complete word is selected in the text editor (when programming with Structured Text). This function makes coding a lot easier because we can identify the variable that we are using anywhere text editor window.

Question:
Is it possible to implement a plug-in or add-on to add this feature to TcXaeShell of TwinCat?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1lEy.png)

Answer (score 1):

[Program Beckhoff PLC in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73891673/program-beckhoff-plc-in-vs-code)

Looking at the comments, the highlighting is coming with build 4026. But this may be quite a long time away since we are currently in build 4024 :/

Comment: Is the new version 4026 coming also with Bookmarks? This basic functionality is also very helpful.

Comment: I am not sure, better to ask the person in the thread that mentioned this. There is probably a video (webinar) archive where they mentioned this.

Comment: They said build 4026 is coming end of the year. As to what features, I do not know.